# Setting scroll position of a div with pure CSS?

Tags: css

I know there are some js solutions, but wondering if there is something simple in CSS I could do. I have a `div` with a set `max-height`, but I want the default position to be scrolled to the bottom of the div content rather than the top of the div. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `naming` to set the scroll. Have some hidden `div` with the name set to `scrollPosition` or something, and then just when linking to the page include the `#scrollPosition` at the end of the URL

Comment: In my case I have multiple of these divs and rewriting the url could be impractical. But yes that's a workable solution for a single-div case!

Comment: When you say multiple div what do you mean? you can only be scrolled to one position at a time. Are you saying the link from another page goes to a different div on the current page depending on the link clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an awfull trick in HTML5, using the attribute autofocus of an input.

This is not CSS, just HTML.

> browser support http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/02-autofocus.html

Set this input *(and hide it)* where you want to scroll down within the content or make it float with a margin-top with the value wanted (px, em, vh, any value/unit).

You can download this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWZyeZ) at http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/YWZyeZ/ *(zip file with HTML + CSS **to run on its own** for testing )* CSS and HTML is the same below in the snippet where  autofocus has no effect here because it is not in  the main document but inside an Iframe .

For a tipycal use, you can easily scroll a chat box all the way down to the input text where you chat ...

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollmedown {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>only works loaded from a real page/uri</h1>
  <p><a href="http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/YWZyeZ/">donwload zip file from codepen</a>
   <br/><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
      elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>
  
  <h3><input autofocus type=text class="scrollmedown">Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

  <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
```